# `PermissionError` occurs when use `os.rename()` or `os.replace()` on files of a Windows ReFS drive mounted to WSL2

Tags: python, wsl-2, refs

My Python project works correctly on Windows but it encounters bugs on WSL2. I have done some debugging and finally localized the error to a compatibility problem. That is, in WSL2, Python's native functions `os.rename()` and `os.replace()` cannot deal with files on a mounted ReFS drive well, and `PermissionError` occurs.

For example, we have a ReFS drive `F` and a file `F:\text.txt` on Windows. Then, `F:` will be mounted to WSL2 as `/mnt/f` and the file path is `/mnt/f/text.txt`. The test with `PermissionError` is:

```py
import os
with open('/mnt/f/text.txt','w'):
    pass

assert os.path.exists('/mnt/f/text.txt')

try:
    os.rename('/mnt/f/text.txt','/mnt/f/text2.txt')
except PermissionError as e:
    print(e)
# [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/f/text.txt' -> '/mnt/f/text2.txt'

try:
    os.replace('/mnt/f/text.txt','/mnt/f/text2.txt')
except PermissionError as e:
    print(e)
# [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/f/text.txt' -> '/mnt/f/text2.txt'

os.remove('/mnt/f/text.txt') # passed
assert not os.path.exists('/mnt/f/text.txt')
```

But, if we turn to a normal NTFS drive, such as `X:`, and the test with no bug is:

```py
import os
with open('/mnt/x/text.txt','w'):
    pass

assert os.path.exists('/mnt/x/text.txt')

try:
    os.rename('/mnt/x/text.txt','/mnt/x/text2.txt')
except PermissionError as e:
    print(e)

with open('/mnt/x/text.txt','w'):
    pass

assert os.path.exists('/mnt/x/text.txt')

try:
    os.replace('/mnt/x/text.txt','/mnt/x/text3.txt')
except PermissionError as e:
    print(e)

assert not os.path.exists('/mnt/x/text.txt')
os.remove('/mnt/x/text2.txt') 
assert not os.path.exists('/mnt/x/text2.txt')
os.remove('/mnt/x/text3.txt') 
assert not os.path.exists('/mnt/x/text3.txt')
```

So, the conclusions from the above tests are:

1. WSL2 and its Python do not completely support ReFS
2. In the Python run on WSL2, `os.rename()` and `os.replace()` do not support files in a ReFS drive that mounted to WSL2
3. `os.remove()` is supported.
4. When it comes to NTFS drive, all the above operations are supported.

To solve the problem, I have tried the following 2 methods but they both do not work respectively:

1. modify `/etc/wsl.conf` by adding:

   ```ini
   [automount]
   options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
   ```

   and then restart WSL2.
2. re-mount target drive by arg `noperm`

   ```bash
   sudo umount /mnt/f
   sudo mount -t drvfs F: /mnt/f -o noperm
   ```

So, how to fix it? How can I rename files in a Windows ReFS dive that is mounted to WSL2?

Thanks in advance.